# ConstraintLayout wrap_content exclude child

Tags: android, layout, constraints

I have a `ConstraintLayout` with `layout_height="wrap_content"`
Inside I have four children. What I need is to constraint the last child to the second one, but I need the last child to be above the `ConstraintLayout` it should be **excluded** from the `wrap_content` of the parent. I'm breaking my head for a few days, I can't find a way to do so. Maybe someone has an idea.

Here is my XML:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button one"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button two"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/status_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:text="Collaps"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button2" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button2" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is what I get:

[image]

This is what I need:

[image]

I know I can constraint the bottom and the top of my `FrameLayout` outside the `ConstraintLayout` to his bottom, but the problem is that I need it to be constrained exactly to `button2` and not to be wrapped by his parent.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If the effect you're after is just to do with the view being 'outside' of the background, then you shouldn't set a background on the `ConstraintLayout` itself, but add another view to represent it. So in your case, you could use something like this:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/status_text_view"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    ...
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: The problem is that the "Container" is a CardView with background.

Comment: Why is that a problem?